# Boostrap 5 Tab content width problem with video and responsive

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I made a tabbed page using tab-pane class in Bootstrap v5. The tabs menu on the left, tab contents on the right with video .Whenever I place an video inside tab-contents with width:100% and height auto then video width do not stretch which leave gap at right after video .Tried to responsive then video will go down bellow tab button.how to make video at right along with responsive?

**code**

```
 <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
    <div className="d-flex align-items-start tabs-outer-cover">
            <div
              className="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3 tabs-cover"
              id="v-pills-tab"
              role="tablist"
              aria-orientation="vertical"
            >
              <button
                className="nav-link active"
                id="v-pills-home-tab"
                data-bs-toggle="pill"
                data-bs-target="#v-pills-home"
                type="button"
                role="tab"
                aria-controls="v-pills-home"
                aria-selected="true"
              >
                Tour
                <span>
                 A journey
                </span>
              </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
    <div className="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
              <div
                className="tab-pane fade show active"
                id="v-pills-home"
                role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab"
                tabindex="0"
              >
                <div className="video-container">
                  <video autoPlay loop muted playsInline>
                    <source
                      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/c/c0/Big_Buck_Bunny_4K.webm/Big_Buck_Bunny_4K.webm.720p.webm"
                      type="video/mp4"
                    />
                  </video>
                </div>
              </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```